# Delete row with shapes.. TopLeftCell Error

Tags: excel, shapes, intersect, vba

I am currently making an excel template for other people in company to use.
I need to delete rows with a single button.
I believe I've done everything correctly, but I am keep getting an error.

Right below you can see the codes which gives error;

```
Worksheets("Storyboard").Activate
Worksheets("Storyboard").Unprotect Password:="**$#B'A1313XQ.;**"

satirlar = Baslangic & ":" & Bitis

For i = Baslangic To Bitis
Dim s As Shape
For Each s In Worksheets("Storyboard").Shapes
    If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, Range("L" & Baslangic & ":" & "L" & Bitis)) Is Nothing Then
        s.Delete
    End If
Next s

Next i

Rows(satirlar).Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

I am keep getting an error on the "s.topleftcell" part. It says that "application-defined or object defined error".

On this code; "Baslangic" and "Bitis" are predefined with a form.

I can use any possible advise here..

Comment: Do you have any data validation dropdowns on your worksheet?

Comment: Actually yes, I have another module to automatically insert a validation to a range for the same sheet. But inside that range of cells, there are no shapes.

Comment: See my suggested answer below then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A data validation (DV) dropdown is a shape, but DV dropdowns don't have a `TopLeftCell` property. What you can do is loop through the `DrawingObjects` instead:

```
For i = Baslangic To Bitis
Dim s As Object
For Each s In Worksheets("Storyboard").DrawingObjects
    If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, Range("L" & Baslangic & ":" & "L" & Bitis)) Is Nothing Then
        s.Delete
    End If
Next s

Next i
```

Comment: Wow, I owe you a big one. This one actually saved me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, try something like this:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim myShape As Shape

    For Each myShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        Debug.Print myShape.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)
        Debug.Print myShape.TopLeftCell.row
    Next myShape

End Sub
```

This is a good way to use the topLeftCell. You can even compare the rows explicitly and make your code without the `Intersect()`.

It would be something like `if myShape.TopLeftCell.row >Baslangic` or similar.

Your code would **probably** work, if you change it to:

```
If Not Intersect(s.TopLeftCell, Worksheets("Storyboard").Range("L" & Baslangic & ":" & "L" & Bitis)) Is Nothing Then
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast reply. Unfortunately this time I keep getting an error at the "Debug.Pring myShape.TopLeftCell.Address(i, "L") line. :( It says that "Application-defined or object-defined error for "myShape.TopLeftCell.Row"

Comment: Leave the 2 zeroes in the address

Comment: With 2 zeros I still get the same error unfortunately. It gives error to this part; {Debug.Print s.TopLeftCell.Address(0, 0)}