# Delete Button to delete relative rows and all buttons in those rows

Tags: excel, vba, button

I have created this delete button that triggers deleting a relative range of rows including all buttons that are within that deleted rows. Sometime that code won't run and it will give me run-time 1004 error "application-defined or object-defined error" and it will highlight the If Not Intersect statement. Sometime it will work just fine. It looks like it depends on what I have done right before I click the bottom. Something is triggering the error. Please help!

```
 Sub Delete_Button()
    'Delete_Button

'Step 1: Select the cell under the clicked button

    Dim r As Range
    Dim s As Shape

    Set r = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell
    Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Select

'Step 2: delete all buttons relative to the selected cell from step 1

    StartCell = ActiveCell.Offset(-5, 0).Address
    EndCell = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Address

    For Each s In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If Not Intersect(Range(StartCell, EndCell), s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
            s.Delete
        End If
    Next s

'Step 3: delete the rows relative to the selected cell from step 1

        ActiveCell.Offset(-7, 0).Rows("1:8").EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
        ActiveCell.Offset(-4, 0).Range("A1").Select

    End Sub
```

Comment: Not saying at what row the error appears it is a little more difficult to receive an answer. Probably, we could understand it deeply analyzing the code, but who spend time with such things...? If sometimes the code works well, this only means that in those situation the problem bothering the code does not appear.

Comment: `Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)).Select` is a strange construction.  `r.Select` will have the same effect. And selecting is not needed at all. Using `r` instead of `ActiveCell` you obtain the same result and may eliminate everything in between the two code lines.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thank you for the reply. I am new to VBA. The error appears at the "If Not Intersect" row. This is the row that gets highlighted in yellow after I get the error and I hit debug.  Btw, I am new to VBA so I hope you understand my struggle. I highly appreciate your help if you have any suggestions on how to write the code differently for the same purpose.

Comment: @FaneDuru if `s.TopLeftCell is not exactly a range` why you can `s.TopLeftCell.address`, `Range(StartCell, EndCell)` until work. I think this is probably a temporary problem and should be careful when using offset~ except can someone tell me what application.caller is for?

Comment: @TheGridLock the macro is assigned to multiple buttons the application.caller is to select the cell of the clicked one then I can offset from there in the next two steps.

Comment: ok, I got it. I often use it in functions but haven't used it on sub.

Comment: @TheGridLock do you suggest any alternative to If Not Intersect(Range(StartCell, EndCell), s.TopLeftCell) Is Nothing Then
        s.Delete

Comment: could be it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43631452/delete-row-with-shapes-topleftcell-error

Comment: @TheGridLock Thank you so much! It seems that changing the DrawingObjects has solved the error. I tried to use it and it is working so far.

Comment: @FaneDuru Thak you for your help as well.I simplified Range(Cells(r.Row, r.Column), Cells(r.Row, r.Column)) using r directly.